# Pymysql UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3

Tags: python, mysql, encoding, pymysql, mysqlbinlog

im using **pymysql, Binlog2sql** every thing works fine with English characters
the **connection string** im using is

```
conn_setting = {'host': args.host, 'port': args.port, 'user': args.user, 'passwd': args.password, 'charset': 'utf8'} # ISO-8859-1 utf8mb4
```

but when using it with **Unicode characters** (Arabic)
i got this error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 70: invalid continuation byte
```

the **database charset is utf8mb4**

i tried other encoding like **ISO-8859-1 , utf8mb4**  but with no luck
the pymysql documentation doesn't specify any charset

*system configuration
pymysql 0.9.3
python 3.10
mysql 8
windows 11 or linux ubuntu 20*
[Binlog2sql](https://github.com/danfengcao/binlog2sql)

**UPDATE #1**
the string I'm trying to decode

```
b"INSERT INTO `db1`.`t3`(`idt3`, `t3col`) VALUES (56, '\xc7\xed');
```

with this code

```
str= str.decode("utf-8")
```

when using Windows-1256 on windows machine it works fine but on linux machine it returns a different text without errors

**UPDATE #2**
this library actually create a temp file then store the quires on it finally it will read it from the file that's why it will messed up the data from the database the file on windows is ANSI encoded
using cp1256 as @Rick James suggested will solve it for both Windows and Linux

Comment: Please show us a few bytes on either side of the E3.

Comment: hi thank you for you replay i managed to solve it by using Windows-1256

Comment: btw this only work in windows in linux it show a different text without any error

Comment: The error means the encoding is *not* UTF-8. UTF8 isn't some kind of escape sequence so "decoding" a string won't do anything. Python strings are already Unicode.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Where did this binary string come from, and why is it a binary string instead of a plain old string with Arabic characters? Python 3 strings are Unicode. Period. You can type any non-English characters you want without a problem or encoding. StackOverflow also uses UTF8 like most web sites. That's why I can type `Αυτό Εδώ`

Comment: MySQL doesn't require escape sequences for non-English text values either. There's no reason to use escape sequences

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - `Αυτό Εδώ` is hex C1F5F4FC20C5E4FE if using character set greek, or CE91CF85CF84CF8C20CE95CEB4CF8E if using character set utf8 (or utf8mb4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cp1256  C7ED maps to 'اي'  -- Is this what you were hoping for?

If so, then establish that the client is using `CHARACTER SET cp1256` in the connection parameters.  Or by using `SET NAMES cp1256 as the first SQL statement after connecting.

You can either have the columns declared character set cp1256 or character set utf8.  MySQL will convert between the client's encoding (cp1256) and the column's (cp1256 or utf8, as you choose in `CREATE TABLE`)

Comment: after debugging this library i found its problem that it will create a temp file on both windows and linux using cp1256 solved the problem